# Define a macro which defines a macro which takes given code w/ arguments

Tags: macros

I have a macro which takes two arguments, a name and the code:

```
\newcommand\definesomething[2]{%
  \@namedef{something@#1}##1{#2}}
\definesomething{whatever}{Code with #1}
\show\something@whatever
```

This works fine, but I would like to change the inner definition so a macro is defined which defines a macro using the given code:

```
\newcommand\definesomething[2]{%
  \@namedef{something@#1}{%
    % ...
    \def\something##1{#2}%
    % ...
  }}
\definesomething{whatever}{Code with #1}
\show\something@whatever
```

Obviously it does not work this way. But how to do this correctly (without using `xparse`)?

Of course I could use a helper macro here, but IMHO this is far from being a good solution:

```
\newcommand\definesomething[2]{%
  \@namedef{something@@#1}##1{#2}% define helper macro
  \@namedef{something@#1}{%
    % ...
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\something\csname something@@#1\endcsname
    % ...
  }}
\definesomething{whatever}{Code with #1}
\show\something@whatever
```

Any idea how to do better?

Addendum 2019-09-14: The user interface (`\definesomething{whatever}{Code with #1}`) needs to remain the same, and I would like to get rid of the extra helper macro `\@namedef{something@@#1}` which is defined ob every usage of `\definesomething`. It would be nice if only `\something@whatever` whould be defined after usage of `\definesomething{whatever}{...}`.

Comment: Traditional TeX-engines don't provide means for doubling hashes outside `\edef`/`\xdef`-contexts. In `\edef`/`\xdef`-contexts both during `\the`-expansion of token-parameters/token-registers and during delivering the balanced text of `\unexpanded` hash-doubling takes place. This is for compensating that the amount of hashes will be halved when expanding the macro that was defined in terms of `\edef`/`\xdef`. Unexpanded-writing (also with `\scantokens`' pseudo-files) also doubles hashes. But reading the (pseudo)-file requires re-tokenization. Hereby catcode-régimes might cause problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If ε-TeX extensions are available, then you can systematically nest `\unexpanded` inside `\edef`.

You can achieve the sequence

`\definesomething{⟨MacroNamePart⟩}{⟨Code with #1⟩}` → define `\something@MacroNamePart`

`\something@MacroNamePart` → define `\something{#1}` → `Code with #1`

as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\definesomething[2]{%
  \expandafter\edef\csname something@#1\endcsname{%
    \unexpanded{\def\something}####1\unexpanded{{#2}}%
  }%
}%

\show\definesomething
\definesomething{whatever}{Code with #1}%

\show\something@whatever
\something@whatever

\show\something

\stop
```

[image]

Each definition-level where the hashes of the parameter of the user-level-macro shall be doubled (so that they can be halved during expansion of the macro) requires another nesting-level of `\unexpanded`.

**As a rule of thumb the only things that must *not* go into `\unexpanded` are the hashes-and-digit-sequences that denote arguments that occur in the `⟨parameter texts⟩` of those macros that get defined via `\edef`.**

The braces wherein the `⟨balanced texts⟩` of the `⟨definition texts⟩` of these `\edef`-definitions are nested also need not to go into `\unexpanded` which makes life easy.

You can easily achieve the sequence

`\definesomething{⟨MacroNamePart⟩}{⟨Code with #1⟩}` → define `\something@DefinitionNestLevelOne`

`\something@DefinitionNestLevelOne` → define `\something@DefinitionNestLevelTwo`

`\something@DefinitionNestLevelTwo` → define `\something@MacroNamePart`

`\something@MacroNamePart` → define `\something{#1}` → `Code with #1`

as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\definesomething[2]{% 
  \edef\something@DefinitionNestLevelOne{%<-opening brace of \edef-definition-text needs not be in \unexpanded
  % here things are surrounded by 1 \edef, thus everything that is not a parameter
  % of this one \edef must be nested in 1 level of \unexpanded:
    \unexpanded{\edef\something@DefinitionNestLevelTwo}{%<-opening brace of \edef-definition-text needs not be in \unexpanded
     % here things are surrounded by 2 \edef, thus everything that is not a parameter
     % of one of these 2 \edef must be nested in 2 levels of \unexpanded:
      \unexpanded{\unexpanded{\expandafter\edef\csname something@#1\endcsname}}{%<-opening brace of \edef-definition-text needs not be in \unexpanded
         % here things are surrounded by 3 \edef, thus everything that is not a parameter
         % of one of these 3 \edef must be nested in 3 levels of \unexpanded:
         \unexpanded{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{\def\something}}}################1\unexpanded{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{{#2}}}}% 
      }%<-closing brace of \edef-definition-text needs not be in \unexpanded
    }%<-closing brace of \edef-definition-text needs not be in \unexpanded
  }%<-closing brace of \edef-definition-text needs not be in \unexpanded
}%

\show\definesomething
\definesomething{whatever}{Code with #1}%

\show\something@DefinitionNestLevelOne
\something@DefinitionNestLevelOne

\show\something@DefinitionNestLevelTwo
\something@DefinitionNestLevelTwo

\show\something@whatever
\something@whatever

\show\something

\stop
```

[image]

---

What can you do if ε-TeX-extensions are not available?

In the very special case that `⟨Code with #1⟩` does only contain `#1` but not `##1` etc,
you can use `⟨Code with #1⟩` for defining a macro which processes one argument, and for multiplying the hashes call that macro with multiple hashes as argument. Could look like this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\definesomething[2]{%
  {%
    \def\tempa##1{\def\tempa{#2}}%
    \tempa{########1}%
    \expandafter
  }\expandafter\innerdefinesomething\expandafter{\tempa}{#1}%
}%

\newcommand\innerdefinesomething[2]{%
  \@namedef{something@#2}{%
    % ...
    \def\something####1{#1}%
    % ...
}}

\show\definesomething
\definesomething{whatever}{Code with #1}%

\show\something@whatever
\something@whatever

\show\something

\stop
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks! (I didn't know about the hash-doubling \unexpanded does.)

Comment: Hash-doubling takes place in `\edef/\xdef`-contexts a) at `\the`-expansion of <token parameters> and <token registers> b) when the <balanced text> of a <general text> forming the argument of  `\unexpanded` is delivered. This compensates hash-halving at the time of expanding macros. And hash-doubling takes place when writing hashes to external file/screen via (`\immediate`)`\write`. It also takes place when `\scantokens`/`\detokenize` do their job of unexpanded-writing a pseudo-file and reading that back under current catcode-régime respective `\string`-catcode-régime.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand the question, but perhaps:

```
> \something@whatever=macro:
->\def \something ##1{Code with ##1}.
l.12 \show\something@whatever

? 
> \something=macro:
#1->Code with #1.
l.16 \show\something

?
```

from

```
\makeatletter

\newcommand\definesomething[2]{%
  \@namedef{something@#1}{%
    % ...
    \def\something####1{#2}%
    % ...
  }}

\definesomething{whatever}{Code with ##1}

\show\something@whatever

\something@whatever

\show\something
```

Comment: Was just about to write the same when your answer popped up :)

Comment: The usage of `\definesomething` must be `\definesomething{whatever}{Code with #1}` (and not `\definesomething{whatever}{Code with ##1}`). I cannot change this for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You can double the `#` tokens by using a token register. However this will require `\edef` and `\unexpanded` in the body of the main definition.

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand\definesomething[2]{%
  \toks@={#2}%
  \expandafter\edef\csname something@#1\endcsname{%
    % ...(all in \unexpanded)
    \def\noexpand\something####1{\the\toks@}%
    % ...(all in \unexpanded)
  }}
\definesomething{whatever}{Code with #1}
\show\something@whatever
\something@whatever
\show\something
```

The console output is

```latex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./as.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
> \something@whatever=macro:
->\def \something ##1{Code with ##1}.
l.10 \show\something@whatever

? 
> \something=macro:
#1->Code with #1.
l.12 \show\something
```